# Is it possible to have a child float over the vertical scroll?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a list in html which has list items and vertical scroll bar is enabled for overflow. One of the children of the list item is an image parked on the right corner of the list item. When mouse is hovered on it, I want to display a flyout which is also a child in the list item. The problem is that the flyout gets chopped but I want it to float and be displayed over the scroll bar when one hovers the mouse. Is it even possible? I am trying to avoid housing the image and flyout outside of the list item because then it would mean we have to calculate the position of it every time we scroll and place it currently in the list item. Also, it is a complicated web page already up and running , so I don't want to mess around too much with the list and scroll bar.

I have created a simpler test.html for the purpose of this question. 
In the code below, lets say I want to have the green block go past the scroll bar when one hovers the mouse. Is it even possible?

I tried making the flyout position = absolute, tried overflow = visible, tried giving insanely large z-index.

```
<style type="text/css">
div#listpanel {
  width: 254px;
  height: 1180px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
div.blackdiv {
  left: 0px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 107px;
  top: 20px;
  background: black;
}
div.greendiv {
  left: 180px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="listpanel">
<div role="list">
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
  <div class="greendiv">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: note: If you add code, you have to either format it as code or put it into a "snippet". Other wise it might not be visible to other users. I edited your code accordingly...

Comment: holy moly thats alot of inline styles!\

Comment: Thank you Johannes! Appreciate it.

Comment: Here is an easier to read version of your markup https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/2ykp85v4/8/

Comment: position:absolute works. I don't see why not. What is the problem? There is no other way to break out, I am pretty sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `top` and `left` styling on your green & black divs do nothing as the divs initially are non-positioned (static) elements.

I then tried to add on-hover styling with `position: absolute;`. For this, you still don't need to add `left` or `right` here to simply pop it out where it currently sits because it will sit relative to it's direct ancestor which is its containing `.blackdiv` div, so it will not go anywhere. If you *do* want to move it elsewhere on-hover, you have to think about where its new position will be, and if your mouse will still be hovering over it or not. I believe this was your issue.

```
/* CSS */
div#listpanel {
  width: 254px;
  height: 580px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

div.blackdiv {
  width: 500px;
  height: 107px;
  background: black;
}

div.greendiv {
  width: 600px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}

div.greendiv:hover {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="listpanel">
    <div role="list">
        <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
            <div class="greendiv">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
            <div class="greendiv">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
            <div class="greendiv">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
            <div class="greendiv">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
            <div class="greendiv">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
            <div class="greendiv">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
            <div class="greendiv">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
            <div class="greendiv">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
            <div class="greendiv">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
            <div class="greendiv">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blackdiv" role="listitem">
            <div class="greendiv">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yxd7mp4c/1/

**Update:** Okay, so this breaks when you scroll down, and it seems due to a similar reason I mentioned above. When the green div becomes `absolute`, it think its parent is positioned where it was on page load, not its new position after scrolling, so it jumps around and you are no longer hovering over it. You will have to use some javascript to bind the on-hover event and offset the position of the flyout relative to the scroll-y position to prevent it from moving around.

Comment: Thank you Nick! This was super helpful!